# Trouble installing "xml2" on R (from Redhat)

Tags: r, tidyverse, redhat, rvest, xml2

I tried installing the packages "tidyverse" and "brms" on R, using the Redhat version of Linux, but had an error message related to "xml2" for both.

Example when trying to install R package "tidyverse":

```
* installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
** package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
ERROR: 'configure' exists but is not executable -- see the 'R Installation and Administration Manual'
* removing ‘/home/davidb/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/xml2’
ERROR: dependency ‘xml2’ is not available for package ‘rvest’
* removing ‘/home/davidb/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/rvest’
ERROR: dependencies ‘rvest’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/davidb/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/tidyverse’
```

Based on what I found on the internet, I understood that xml2 depends on libxml2, which I installed with the following command:

`sudo yum install -y libcurl-devel openssl-devel libxml2-devel`

After that, when opening R and trying `install.packages("xml2")`, I still got an error message:

````
* installing *source* package ‘xml2’ ...
** package ‘xml2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
ERROR: 'configure' exists but is not executable -- see the 'R Installation and Administration Manual'
* removiError: unexpected '>' in ">"
ng ‘/home/davidb/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/xml2’```

Any help would be welcome!

R session details:
```> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "linux-gnu"

$system
[1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "4"

$minor
[1] "0.3"

$year
[1] "2020"

$month
[1] "10"

$day
[1] "10"

$`svn rev`
[1] "79318"

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)"

$nickname
[1] "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out"```
````